# Консоль выводит NaN

Tags: c#

```
 double y = Math.Pow(Math.Log(0.2 + Math.Sin(x)), 2);
```

При вводе некоторых чисел например 4,5 выводит Nan все перепробовал и на -1 домножал и по модулю брал все-ровно NaN

Comment: Пробовали-то на бумажке с ручкой посчитать результат самостоятельно?

Comment: да, конечно ничем не отличается от других

Comment: И сколько же вы насчитали при x=4.5?

Comment: я не брал  x =4.5 у меня было от 1 до 10 с шагом 1

Comment: У вас в вопросе записано именно число 4.5 — оформляйте вопросы нормально, чтобы не вводить в заблуждение. После разделяющих запятых всегда ставится пробел.

Comment: Но хорошо, давайте возьмём число 4 — сколько же вы насчитали при x=4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Math.Sin(4.5) = -0.977, если прибавить 0.2 будет отрицательное число, которое не может быть аргументом Math.log
И при других значениях синус может принимать значения менее чем -0.2 и будет NaN

Comment: @Kioshilol как-то странно вы считали на бумажке с ручкой, если до этого не разобрались

Comment: @andreymal я не знал что log не может принять отрицательное число (вернее позабыл) и поэтому проверял y на отрицательное значение, я знал что синус отрицательный